# How you document your web browsers requirements?

Tags: testing, web, cross-browser, browser-support

All,

I'm looking for an advice, how you normally document web browsers requirements in your requirement document.

1) Do you mention the browsers type that your application must support e.g. Chrome / Firefox / IE? Do you also mention the version number ? the 32/64 bit ? and the Operating Systems that the browsers is installed? How far you go on documenting the requirements?

2) What should be the testing strategy to test the browser combination? e.g. should you just test the last 2 version? i.e. firefox version 22 and 23

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Web browser requirements are part of the "Supported Platforms requirement" topic for which you end up having huge matrix made of Browser type (Chrome, FF etc.), Browser version, OS type, OS version (including 32/64 bits), and anything else that could be on different version for users (Java, Python, Ruby etc.). So to answer your questions:

1. I would go as far as possible in the detail in the requirements of the browser/platform, so that the dev, QA, doc, support etc. teams know what browser/platform is supposed to work
2. For the browser combination, take into account that more and more browsers are on auto-update mode. For example, most of the people have the last version of Chrome so we might test only the last or 2 last ones.

Comment: thanks Laurent - so in your unit test / system test / uat - which browsers should i use to test? obviously it is impossible to test all possible combinations?

Comment: depends on som many things... In our team we try to use different browser among the QA workforce (but mainly FF and Chrome). It also depends if you have the feeling you are very browser dependent: for example, if your web app is mostly JQuery based, you rely also a lot on JQuery own tests. (not sure my answer will help you much...)